# Implications of group mean centering predictors in unbalanced, multi-level modelling

Tags: multilevel-analysis, centering

As we all know, centering predictor variables is an important topic in statistical inference, and can severely influence interpretations of parameters for lay audiences. In multilevel models, centering can be even trickier, as researchers need to decide between centering within clusters or between clusters. The latter is known as group-mean centering, where each cluster's level-1 predictor values are centered around the grand mean of the level 1 predictor across clusters. However, this would imply that the grand mean has meaning for all clusters.

My question is: **what are the implications of grand-mean centering when we have unbalanced data?** Take the example of [behavioural reaction norms](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19748700) in behavioural ecology, where multilevel models are used to decompose individual variation into different components, namely random intercepts and slopes. Animal personality, individual differences in how animals behaviour *on average*, is investigated by assessing individual variation in random intercepts over the average of repeated time-points, and thus requires grand-mean centering (intercepts are interpretable when the level 1 predictor = 0).

However, say we have a number of unbalanced repeated measurements. We are still interested in assessing how animals differ on average from each other. If we group-mean centre in this scenario, does the individual variation of the random intercepts only apply to those individuals who have data at the grand-mean value of the level 1 predictor? How biased might these estimates be, then, when the grand mean of the data doesn't apply to a large number of individuals?

I hope this question is clear! And thanks for any insights.